# Test question need help

Tags: questions

I am a Portuguese High School student and I did an English test last September.  This question came up:

> You can also get some insight from television and movies, but be
>   careful - not everything you see on the screen is meant to be
>   realistic. But these media do help if you're still trying to learn the
>   language or catch up on some slang, and at the very least, give you
>   something to talk about when you're trying to make a new friend.

Question:

> What does the word 'these' refer to?

I answered that 'these' refers to 'television and movie. The Teacher said that I was wrong, and I lost some points.

Am I wrong or right?

Please ... I need answers to defend myself.

Comment: *Media* means "mediums of transmission," so "these media" refers to television and movies.  What did your teacher say the word referred to?

Comment: Television and movies.

Comment: Hello, Sandro. deadrat has given the 'correct' answer, but I'm not sure it was all that wise. If you go and show your teacher the error of their ways (I'm assuming 'defend myself' means 'show them I'm right'), you will end up with a bigger problem than a minor injustice.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 

It is something i really need to do, because the teacher now is always bullying me because I said that she was right

I know i am right with the answer Television and Movies, the Teacher said it was wrong, the right answer was Media..

Comment: You need to see another responsible person about what's going on, not just mention a website.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm doing it, this is just one of the proof.. 

Thank you.. Really..

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I make no comment on the wisdom of confronting ignorant authority, just on an antecedent.

Comment: Teachers are often wrong, but telling you you're wrong is not necessarily bullying. Telling a teacher bluntly "you're wrong" is just asking for trouble and never helps you or them. Take it as a learning experience about human nature and move on.

Comment: Speaking as a teacher, I don't mind at all if students point out mistakes I have made or bring up questions about things I teach.  I've had rude students and polite students.  Now, I don't care if the student is rude or polite...I just examine what they're saying and if I'm wrong, I say sorry, if they are wrong, I try to help them see why they are wrong.  Choose your battles wisely. if it's 3 points and you still have six months left with this person and they aren't being reasonable, forget about it and move on.

Comment: On another note, did the teacher write the example paragraph herself, or was it from a textbook?  Also, what were the subjects you were studying in the last two weeks?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** It comes down to the meaning of the word "refer" in your test question, which asked, "What does the word 'these' refer to?".

If the question is interpreted as asking for "these [*what*]", where you need to supply the [*what*], then the question is asking for a [modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_modifier) as @deadrat noted in comments. In this case, the appropriate answer would be *media*. [Similar example: in the phrase "green grass and blue sky", the word 'green' *refers* to the grass].

On the other hand, if the question is interpreted as asking you to replace the word *these* with other words from the paragraph, then the question is asking for the antecedent to the [anaphor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_%28linguistics%29), namely, "television and movies". [Similar example: in the sentence "Annie walked her dog.", the word 'her' *refers* to Annie, not the dog.]

The 'correct' answer would depend on what *refer* is asking for. If this is not implicitly or explicitly stated in the broader context of the test, then there is a case for both answers to be considered correct, with the anaphor interpretation arguably the stronger case.

---

Technically, both are correct. You say *these* refers to "television and movies", while your comments under your question indicate that your teacher says it refers to "media".

In the immediate phrase *these media*, *these* refers syntactically to *media*. However, the first sentence also specifies the specific media under discussion in the context of the paragraph, so *television and movies* are the specific media referred to by *these* (i.e. not novels, paintings, etc).

Comment: *These* doesn't refer to *media*; *these* modifies *media*.

Comment: @deadrat Fair enough regarding *modifies*. However, in the context of this question, *media* a valid referent of *these*. I think there's enough breadth to the word *refer* that the answers of both student and teacher should be allowed.

Comment: At the risk of turning into That Internet Guy Who Has to Have the Last Word, a referent is a pointer.  For an anaphoric pronoun (i.e., a following pronoun) the referent is also the antecedent.  You should be able to replace the pronoun or the pronoun determiner+noun with the referent.  So "these media do help" -> "television and movies do help".  You can't do that with *these* and *media*.

Comment: @deadrat Thanks - that crystallises the issue. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I think that "these" refers to medias whose meaning is unrealistic
only them while there is some rare medias that are not so.

Comment: `medias` is not the plural of `media` :)